# Official support for fair lock in Python

Tags: java, python, multithreading, locking

Is there an official support for fair reentrant lock in Python language? Just similar to the Java ReentrantLock class

Answer (score 0):

RLock appears to be the closest thing we have, but AFAIK it's CPython under the hood. If you want to make sure that the implementation is closer to Java maybe Jython is for you?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.RLock

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Charles. I am playing with RLock, but it seems to be unfair. Or at least I cannot find any docs that say it is a fair lock.

Comment: Yes it looks like you would have to implement that yourself with the `Condition` class described in the same page I linked to you, unless I'm missing something @dibugger